# Cocos2d v3.4 Templates

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d

How to create cocos2d v3.4 without using Cocos2D-SpriteBuilder?

I installed Cocos2D-SpriteBuilder as they recommended in cocos2d blog:

http://cocos2d.spritebuilder.com/get-started

But I need to create cocos2d v3.4 project from Xcode without creating it first in Cocos2D-SpriteBuilder.

[image]

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the info found [here](http://cocos2d-objc.org/started/), currently there is no official way to achieve this but they are working on it. Meanwhile you can download the "standalone template" found in the same link.

Answer (score 1):

As I recall, as from Cocos2Dv3 you can only create cocos2d projects via SpriteBuilder.
If you insist to work without SB, What I'd recommend is to create a new SpriteBuilder project and delete all the SB files from there. Another option would be to copy all the source files from the sb project to the new Xcode project.

Hope it helped.

Comment: Sure it helped thanks. I have one more question if you don't mind.It's normal that cocos2d doesn't appear with Xcode templates as shown in the image?

Comment: It's fine. Spritebuilder does that for you. Just create a Spritebuilder project and it's automatically generating a .xcodeproj file for you.

Answer (score -3):

Oh yeah!

Finally solved!

Get it if someone need: [cocos2d v3.4.9 template](http://depositfiles.com/files/gv1i6duc0)

Comment: Could you describe what you did to resolve your issue? This could help others without them required to download anything?